# How to get the Azure Webapp App Settings from Django

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service

Azure Webapp has some variables in App-settings which can be found in the portal as the following image:

[image]

***Question***: How can I get these values in my Django code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

those are just environment variables, so just get them:

```
import os
var = os.environ.get('setting_name')
```